An erratum in Allan Gibbard's "Manipulation of Voting Schemes: A General Result"
This question is in the philosophy site but it could have been in the one about mathematics, more ideally in a "voting theory" site. It's here because Gibbard was most of all a philosoph.
I'm reading Alan Gibbard's Manipulatiokn of Voting Schemes: A General Result and have the feeling that there's a typo, but I'd like to check with you.
When Gibbard defines the concept of manipulability of a voting scheme (straddling pages 4 and 5), he writes the formula
v(P'1,...,P'n) Pk v(P1,...,Pn).
Shouldn't it be
v(P'1,...,P'n) ≠ v(P1,...,Pn)
instead?
I'm sorry: MathJax doesn't seem to work here.

The text looks correct to me. Bear in mind Pk is a preference relation, so it can be read as 'person k prefers'. So the formula is saying that person k prefers the outcome of their professed preferences to the outcome of their actual preferences.

Yes, you're absolutely right. Sorry for the delay, I've discovered the liberal paradox meanwhile.
